# Trying to better understand pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I thought I had a rudimentary understanding of them, but apparently I have none whatsoever.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *x, char *name)
{
    *x = 4;
    *name = "stan";
}

int main()
{
    int y = 10;
    char name = "bob";
    f(&y, &name);
    printf("%d and %s\n", y, name);
}
```

Originally it was just a test using ints, but then I added a second parameter to the f function to test with chars and now I can't get the code to compile. I want to understand but I can't seem to.

Comment: did this code ever work before you were using pointers? `char name = "bob";`?

Comment: Your understanding for `int` is correct. Your understanding for c-strings is very, very wrong. In general, I recommend reading some tutorials on [strings in c](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm). `char` is simply an 8-bit signed integer. A string in C is an array of `chars`, typically represented as either `char[]` or `char*`, where the latter is a pointer to the head of an array of `char`.

Comment: a string in c is a pointer to char (hence char* mystring; or char mystring[]). Hogan:a char is a 8 bit integer, so there is an implicit cast from char* to char and the pointer is truncated. Some compilers need flags to warn you about this

Comment: You can't say char name = "bob", do you even know what mean char ?

Comment: [Questions on C Strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148071/questions-on-c-strings).

Comment: @xsami actually you can thanks to an implicit cast from `char*` to `char`, though most compilers will yell at you if you have warnings enabled since 99.99% of the time that's not the correct thing to do and is instead someone making this exact mistake.

Comment: @aruisdante yeah thanks i knew it, but the thing is that i don't consider this like a place to be debugging compilations error.

Comment: No I thought it was a place for people to come with programming questions when they want to understand a topic or concept better. Apparently you think otherwise?

Comment: @Lectem - yes I know it would set name to 'b' -- the question was rhetorical.

Comment: @Hogan it doesnt set name to b, it sets it to the adress of the string "bob" (usually in the program code memory) and truncates it to fit in a char

Comment: @Lectem - no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Hogan take `char * s = "bob"` for example, it stores the adress of the "bob" string, and put it into the "s" pointer. What I'm saying is that `char  name = "bob";` is the same as `char name = (char) s;`. Hence the truncation since pointers are usually wider than 8bits. Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @Lectem - sure that is 100% correct.  It has nothing to do with "it sets it to the address of the string" as you said in your first comment.  Address and pointers are not at issue when casting from string to char.

Comment: @Hogan "yes I know it would set name to 'b' " -> I still find it correct to say that `name` would have as value the adress of the string truncated and not the ASCII value of character 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code that will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int *x, char **name)
{
    *x = 4;
    *name = "stan";
}

int main()
{
    int y = 10;
    char *name = "bob";

    f(&y, &name);
    printf("%d and %s\n", y, name);
}
```

Comment: This does indeed work for me, I also think it helped me understand chars and strings in C a bit better as well, thanks.

Comment: YAY.  -- Here is the biggest thing that helped me... to learn that in C there is no difference between a c char pointer and a c char array and a string.

Comment: I don't think that is an accurate statement. What I'm learning is that pointers and arrays can be used for many of the same things, but aren't actually the same thing.

Comment: In C they are the same thing.  `a[c] = x;`  is the same as `*(a+c) = x;`  In any place you have one you can replace it with the other and every C compiler will compile it the same.  This is part of the definition of the language.

Comment: I understand this is a hard idea to grasp.  It took me a couple of years.  Come back to it after programming with C for a while and I bet it will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an array of `char` to actually store a string in it, the string is basically an ordered collection of characters so C-strings get quite intuitive after a while.
For "bob" You need `char name[4];` as "bob" will store 4 characters (read about NULL termination). But for "stan" You need 5 chars, so You have to know in advance what You'll store in the string.
To pass the array to a function that takes a pointer just call `f(&y, name)` as array is degraded to a pointer to it's first element when passed to a function (in C and C++ the array can be treated as a pointer in many cases). This will be enough for a proper, NULL-terminated string, normally You would also add an int as a parameter to tell the function what the size of array is.
If You want to assign a string literal like "stan" to an array of char (pointer to char) in `f` don't dereference a pointer, write `name="stan";` since `char*` is something like `char[]`.
Sometimes the mixing of array and pointer can get You dizzy but when You get the hang of it You'll find it easy, the same with C-string.